# Kafka Streams low level processor API's punctuate don't run periodically

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have one `processor` named `AddCashProcessor`.

In `AddCashProcessor`, i maintain a `KeyValueStore<String, HashSet<String>>` to record the userid of who pay for the item by `process` method. The code like this:

```
@Override
public void process(String key, String value) {
    HashSet<String> set = Optional.ofNullable(store.get(key)).orElse(new HashSet<>());
    set.add(value);
    store.put(key, set);
}
```

And in `punctuate` method of a class named `AddCashPunctuator` which `implements the Punctuator interface`, i get the `HashSet.size()` to insert it to MySQL:

```
@Override
public void punctuate(long l) {
    List<String> updateSqls = new ArrayList<>();

    KeyValueIterator<String, HashSet<String>> iter = store.all();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        KeyValue<String, HashSet<String>> entry = iter.next();
            int size = entry.getValue().size();
            ....
        }
    }
    iter.close();

    MySqlUtils.update(updateSqls);

}
```

The `AddCashPunctuator` is registered in `init` method in `AddCashProcessor`, like this:

```
@Override
public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    ....
    this.context.schedule(30000L, PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME, new AddCashPunctuator());
}
```

I want to execute the `punctuate` method every 30 seconds. But it not do it like this.Sometimes it runs well, sometimes pause. When the end of the pause, many times are performed.

Why is it this? Is it because the data of the `HashSet` or `KeyValueStore` too big?
My kafka streams version is 1.0.0.  And my kafka version is 0.10.1.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Kafka Streams there is a single thread that is responsible for regular processing and punctuations. Thus, calls to punctuate can be delayed if your processing takes longer than your punctuation schedule. Independent from this, a GC pause could delay punctuations.

Thus, punctuations (for any system with GC pauses) are best effort (even if there is a dedicated punctuation thread).

If a punctuation was missed, unfortunately, Kafka Streams replays all missed punctuations. This is the reason why you get multiple at once. There is already a fix for upcoming 1.1 release (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6323).

Comment: My code of maintaining HashSet Store is:  

    HashSet<String> set = Optional.ofNullable(store.get(key)).orElse(new HashSet<>());
    set.add(value);
    store.put(key, set);

Every record forward to process method will exec  store.put(key, HashSet).

If it will exec serialize/deserialize or save to storage?  I guss this is a pause point. And what is the corrent way to maintain the HashSet Store?

Comment: Hard to say. Just adding something to the store should not be expensive. Maybe iterating over the complete store in `punctuate()` itself is more time consuming. Check JMX metrics to get more insight. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html#accessing-metrics